# Possible To Convert To Inline If?

Tags: c#, if-statement, conditional-operator

I have this code:

```
if (date.Equals(DateTime.MinValue))
{
    this.textBox.Text = string.Empty;
}
else
{
    if (!myList.Any())
    {
        this.textBox.Text = 
        CheckIfSaturdayOrSunday(date).ToShortDateString();
    }
    else
    {
        this.textBox.Text = CheckMyList(date, 
            myList).ToShortDateString();
    }
}
```

I was wondering if it was possible to consolidate that all into a nested inline if?

If not, I'll just keep it as is.

Thanks!

Comment: You could, but why? It would likely be far less readable.

Comment: `CheckIfSaturdayOrSunday` returns a `DateTime` and not a `bool`? Strange

Comment: I understand this format is more readable, but I know that upon going through code review, I will more than likely get asked to convert it to an inline if.

Comment: Then it's your job to say why it shouldn't be inlined.

Comment: I'd also question what kind of reviewer would require this to be inlined in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need to inline, keep the inline as short as possible, otherwise it's going to be a mess.

```
var text = string.Empty;

if (!date.Equals(DateTime.MinValue))
{
   var dateCheck = myList.Any() ? 
      CheckMyList(date, myList) : CheckIfSaturdayOrSunday(date);

   text = dateCheck.ToShortDateString();
}

this.textBox.Text = text;
```

Comment: Yeah, I like this

Answer (score 0):

You could do this. This is a good balance between readability and condensing.
I don't think that nesting inline ifs is a good idea, it makes it hard to read.

```
if (date.Equals(DateTime.MinValue))
{
    this.textBox.Text = string.Empty;
}
else
{
    this.textBox.Text = myList.Any() ? 
         CheckMyList(date, myList).ToShortDateString(); :
         CheckIfSaturdayOrSunday(date).ToShortDateString();

}
```

Comment: I would say this is worse as you're now mixing methods.